# google page rank algorithm with range of values

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

According to the wikipedia article, the iterative google page rank algorithm is defined as follows:
[image]

Can this be modified to include a range of values, not just binary, and would it look something like this:
[image]
*(where V is the value of any person i at time 0, N the total number of people)*
[image]
*(where V is the value of any person i, d is the “damping factor”, N the total number of people, M the set of people who evaluate person i, the value of pj at time t)*

If not, **what is the equation that replaces link/not with a range, eg 0 to 10?**